# How to change contact's photo under Android 8.0

Tags: contacts, photos, 8.0-oreo, contact-photo, motorola-moto-z2-play

I am trying to change a contact's photo under my Motorola Moto Z2 Play / Android 8.0.0 (Security Patch July 2019):

> Contacts >  (find a contact) >  (edit contact) >  (change photo) > Select new photo

and I am hit with an error saying:

> No pictures are available on the device.

I don't understand this situation, because:

- I have dozens of photos and pictures on this device, in "DCIM", "Pictures" and others,
- I can change widget's icon without any problem (my launcher allows this),
- I've been changing contacts' photos many times on this device.
- I've managed to change contact's photo on other devices and Android versions (A9 and One),
- I don't think this is due to SAF (details: [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/226441/20449) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225940/20449)), because I am still on A8, not A10.

Since I did this last time a couple of months / maybe a year ago. The only thing that comes to my mind is that I did this last time under old, good Android 7.1.2. And the recent update to Android 8.0.0 maybe messed up something.

I have tried putting new photo into every folder that came to my mind:

- root,
- DCIM,
- DCIM/Camera,
- Pictures,
- Pictures/Contacts (I've been using this one for years).

All for nothing. Always seeing this damn message.

I even went as far as:

- Contacts >  (find a contact) >  (edit contact) >  (change photo) > Take new photo,
- capture some test image,
- use it,
- see, where it is stored (turned out that in: DCIM/Camera, as expected),
- remove it,
- try again using "Select new photo".

My phone went as wako as allowing me to change the photo of one of contacts in the first place (i.e. after using "Take new photo"), stored it in DCIM/Camera folder and when I tried to use the very same photo from the very same folder, but using "Select new photo" instead, it again claimed that I have no pictures in this device).

Can anyone help me? How to workaround this problem? How to change contact's photo in A8?

Comment: Please, see the updated question. I will review your suggestion (i.e. installing "Local Storage" app), but I don't think it is going to change anything since SAF was introduced in Android 10 and I still have Android 8 (which shouldn't be aware of the SAF restrictions in theory).

Comment: Taking a shot in the dark: 1) Does the Contacts app have Storage permission? 2) Does it have a built-in file picker, or instead allow the user to choose which app to select the photo?

Comment: @beeshyams An update to your ideas: Still nothing. Seems to be another bug. Using "Local Storage" gave nothing (app can display images without any problems and claims that other apps also should be able to do this). Clearing the media storage app cache (along with data) and restarting this app and the whole phone gives nothing. Waited about half an hour for the index to be rebuilt. Running AZ Media Scanner also did nothing. App reported that scan is completed and that there are no .nomedia files in the folders of my interest. Thanks for trying to help. Seems like another stupidity in Android.

Comment: @AndrewT. I've been using this app, changing contact's images for 2-3 years now. The only change that could happen was update of my system from A7.1 to A8.0. It has all the permissions, it has a file picker. As I wrote in a question, I forced it to shoot a brand new photo and it allowed me to use it as a contact image. It stored it in DCIM/Camera. When I tried to do the same with stored images, it stopped seeing the very same photo, it did itself and claimed that there are no photos in the device. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Just to confirm it's a bug, try using a different contacts & camera app

Comment: This is not a bug. All three contact apps that I tested failed with the same error. Additionally, all my custom ringtones were reset to default one, as I have just discovered. This seems to be a wider problem, so I created a separate question for this and I am going to close this one --> https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226613/20449