# Certain "core" apps lost access to media files

Tags: contacts, photos, 8.0-oreo, contact-photo, motorola-moto-z2-play

At some point in time (about a week ago) *something* happened to my Motorola Moto Z2 Play / Android 8.0 that caused my base apps to not have access to my media files (i.e. audio, photos etc.).

Examples:

- all my custom ringtones (i.e. based on my own media files) were reset to default sound:

  - Contact apps reset custom ringtones for contacts to default one,
  - Alarms & Clock app reset custom alarm tone to default one,
  - SMS (Messages) app reset custom message notification tone to default one,
  - system-wide default notification tone (set by me to custom) was reset as well,
  - system-wide default ringtone (set by me to custom one) was reset,
- [I cannot pick a photo for a contact](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226466/20449) because my contacts app keeps saying: "No pictures are available on the device".

While first situation is resolved. I see my custom ringtone files in the list and I can go through my contacts and assign them again. But second situation is not resolved. I see this error all the time and I cannot change any contact's photo.

This is verified as not a bug (tested three different contacts-like applications and all of them shows exactly the same message, when trying to change contact's photo). But still, it seems that problem is limited to contacts-related apps only. Other apps still has read and write access to my custom files.

For example: :

- (read) I can pick any photo or other custom file and attach it to an e-mail, send it as MMS or share it in any other way or
- (read) upload it to OneDrive or Google Drive etc. or
- (write) my Camera app is still able to make new photos and store them in "DCIM" or
- (write) my sound recorder is able to record sound and write audio files.

The only thing that has changed on my phone recently and that I suspect as the cause of above metioned situation was Android 7.1.2 --> Android 8.0.0 update.

Is there anything I can do (since replacing contacts app didn't resolve the situation) or check in this case? Or resetting the phone to factory defaults is the only option that I am left with?

**EDIT**: *I have cleared cache and data of media app, as suggested in comment. It didn't help.*

Comment: It seems your media store database got corrupted. Did you try clearing cache of Media Storage app and then forcing media scanning? Some details here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209119/218526

Comment: @IrfanLatif As in an updated question -- I did so and there was no effect. Plus, it seems that more apps were affected by the "reset custom tone to default one" problem.

Answer (score 1):

• I think there are two options to change contact's photo- Take a photo and select a photo. Does the take photo option works. Or try changing the app to choose photos for changing the pic.
• If your contacts are backed upto Google then you can goto
https://contacts.google.com/ sign in with the account and can change the contcat pic.
Upvote if it helps.

Comment: Either I am missing something or you are answering a wrong question. Your answer belongs to my other question ([here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226466/how-to-change-contacts-photo-under-android-8-0)), about changing contacts photo. This question is about no access to media files by base apps.