# I am not able to write to the directory Android/data or /Android/obb in android 11?

Tags: applications, android-11

I was trying to add some obb data files to the obb directory in Android folder but every time I made a try it pops an error message, first I thought that this may be because of some fault in File Manager. Than I tried some external File Managers like Solid Explorer and Files by google , but for my surprise I was not even able to access the Android folder in any another external file manager (Android folder was empty no data, no obb was there), than I searched on internet and found this is because of scoped storage (introduced in android 10)

---

I didn't understood much about scoped storage but only that this limits access of apps to the Storage, ***I want to understand more about scoped storage and want to know how this is helpful to us and how I can access those data and obb folders***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android can't view local content after OS upgrade](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225933/android-cant-view-local-content-after-os-upgrade)

Comment: @beeshyams i am able to read files in android/data on system file explorer but not able to write there, so it means i have read access but not write access, is there a way i can write data in those folders, and thanks for your comment it really meant alot to me

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with Android 11

Comment: okkk no problem